# Delphi 2007 - How to avoid having a \history folder?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Newer Delphi versions (including Delphi 2007, which I'm using) have a build in file history feature, which lets you revert to old files from within the IDE.  That's nice, but I already have source control.  Is it possible to disable this feature?

I ask because the IDE auto-creates a \history folder with old versions of all your files, and that annoys me.

Comment: The history folder isn't really for source control. It is so you can make small "experimental" modifications, while being able to revert to an earlier, unchecked in version. Unless you want to check in each save...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Tools \ Options \ Editor Options \

Uncheck "Create Backup Files"

;)

Answer (score 7):

I believe you can go into the registry:

```
D2007: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\BDS\5.0\Known IDE Packages
D2009: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\Known IDE Packages
```

and delete the appropriate key:

```
$(BDS)\bin\historyide100.bpl
or
$(BDS)\bin\historyide120.bpl
```

I'm sure that worked for me and I seem to recall that was all that was needed. I tend not to bother now though and just leave it in. Tell SVN to ignore the history folders.
Any Delphi update does seem to put it back too.

Comment: It still creates the _history folder :(

However, it does get rid of the history tab in the IDE, and the _history folder is totally empty, so this is the best solution yet...

Comment: Rather then delete i would rename it in $(BDS)\bin\XXhistoryide120.bpl, just in case you need it back.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe you can.  If you go to

> Tools \ Options \ Editor Options \
>   File backup limit

Which is where controls how many files it backs up, the minimum is 1, which would still create the history folder.

Maybe you could setup an MSBuild event to clear it out or some other house keeping task.

Comment: Thank you, Jim. I was working on a project the other day and had a good working example. I messed up and started to add in other code, and I removed what was working, and now I am lost. As the backup did not go far enough back. I set it to 90 now, so that I can hopefully go back (in the future) to a working project.

Answer (score 5):

IIRC Delphi Distiller has an option to keep it from creating History folders.  I don't actually have it on my current system, though, so I can't check.  But you might want to check it out.

Answer (score 5):

[DDevExtension](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=10) by Andreas Hausladen has a feature to remove __history directories.

Answer (score 3):

In Delphi 10.3, this has been moved to Tools -> Options -> User Interface -> Editor -> Create Backup Files