# Is there a way to move the __history folders to another directory?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am using source control for all Delphi projects and I am a little bit annoyed by the `__history` folders. It's possible to disable this feature as described here:

[Delphi 2007 - How to avoid having a \history folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836877/delphi-2007-how-to-avoid-having-a-history-folder)

I find the history feature useful, but don't want to have the `__history` folders in my source code. Is it possible to make the IDE write the history files outside of the source code folder?

Comment: u may setup version controls to ignore those history folders

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes, but it would be nice if they weren't there in the first place. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that you can't keep the functionality and have the `__history` directories stored elsewhere. If you want the functionality then you need the folders alongside your source code.

The folders are hidden and so long as you configure your revision control system properly, you never need to be aware of them.

I would also recommend using Andreas Hausladen's [DDevExtensions](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/ide-tools/ddevextensions/) which has a feature to delete the `__history` folders when they are empty.

[image]

Comment: I understodd the question as "Is it possible to make the IDE write the history files outside of the source code folder". Does DDevExtension enable this?

Comment: @David - read the caption of the checkbox. It does not talk about supression, but only about removing unused (empty) ones

Comment: I use this feature as configured in the screenshot. I still have the functionality, but I never see the folders when committing. I confess that I never really dug in to it more deeply. It seems that my understanding was wrong. I've added another paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Never used the following from the [DelphiPRAXiS thread "Pfad für Sicherungsdateien (__history) ändern"](http://www.delphipraxis.net/161571-pfad-fuer-sicherungsdateien-__history-aendern.html), but maybe it helps

[History Locator SVN Link](http://theunknownones.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Delphi/HistoryRelocator/)